# How do u find the log likelihood function of Y^1/2 = XB + u?

Tags: likelihood, extreme-value

Let $Y_i>0$ for all $Y_i$ and $u_i \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$. Where the $u_i$ are iid.

How do you find the log-likelihood function of $Y_i ^{1/2} = B X_i + u_i$?

I am confused because the dependent variable is square-rooted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's $u$ that has the specified distribution here so why could you not just

1. write the (log-)likelihood for $u=(u_1,...,u_n)$ and then
2. replace $u_i$ by the equivalent $\sqrt{y_i}-X_iB$?

Equivalently, let $Y^* = \sqrt{Y}$ and rewrite your (log-)likelihood in terms of that new variable (the model is just $Y^*=XB+u$...)

The new variable is observed in the same sense that $Y$ is -- any time you have a $y_i$ you have a $y_i^*$ -- as far as I can see there's no need to worry about Jacobians or anything here.

There are some issues with the fact that $\sqrt{Y}$ literally *can't* be conditionally normal -- note that $\sqrt{Y}$ has 0 probability of being negative but $XB+u$ has a non-zero probability of being negative -- but that's an issue of model specification rather than a difficulty in the algebra per se. If you ignore it there should be no particular difficulty as long as the model gives a reasonable description of the conditional distribution; in some situations you might get negative predictions (or occasionally even fitted values) for $\sqrt{y}$ but that's not the fault of anything but the person choosing to fit the model in those circumstances.

However, note that you no longer have a model for the mean of $Y$, but for the mean of $Y^*$, and $E(Y)\neq E(\sqrt{Y})^2$. If there's any variation in $Y$, the square of the predicted $Y^*$ will be too small if you want to predict $Y$ (a [Taylor expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_expansions_for_the_moments_of_functions_of_random_variables) can give an approximate adjustment). Similarly you can't just take confidence intervals for the mean across. On the other hand prediction intervals should work reasonably well if you just transform the endpoints.